# case when has problem, other case don't work well

Tags: oracle

I think the 'used' result d,c,cc but i just receive 0.

I think `nvl(used)=0` is right so 'used' set '0', but another else exists so it show another value
if Nested case statement works well

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN NVL (used, 0) = 0
          THEN
             '0'
          WHEN cd = '30'
          THEN
             CASE WHEN MOD (cre, 60) = 0 THEN 'd' ELSE 'c' END
          ELSE
             'cc'
       END
          AS soso
  FROM x;
```

no error but used has '0' value

Comment: Sample data would probably help. If you get 0 as a result, it means that `used` is either 0 or NULL so ... that's what you get.

Comment: Case statements are evaluated in the order they are specified. This means that if `NVL(used, 0) = 0` then the value of "soso" becomes "0". The rest is completely ignored. If this is not want you want, you might consider changing the order within the case statement.

Comment: thank you so i change my code, but i don't know case somthing when and case when someting is different to use. i know if we need much protasis we use case when. i thought than '0' when  cd = '30' are two protasis but this time, i acknowledge it's not., this problem is hard. and thank you